# Case Statement With Between Clause In Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am used to get parameters to my Stored Procedure with a default value ''. I want to check whether if the Date is selected and , if so I want to Execute My Between Clause. In Normal Scenario I am gonna do like this

```
SELECT tbl1.Column1,tbl1.Column2 FROM table1 tbl1
WHERE tbl1.Column1 = CASE WHEN @Column1Val = '' THEN tbl1.Column1 ELSE @Column1Val END
```

But I can't Do this with Between Clause. I can't figure a way to do this other than dynamic query. Is there a way other than Dynamic Query?

This is what I am Trying to do

```
SELECT tbl1.Column1,tbl1.Column2 FROM table1 tbl1
WHERE tbl1.txnDate = CASE WHEN @DateTo = '1900-01-01' AND @DateFrom = '1900-01-01' 
                          THEN  CAST(tbl1.txnDate AS DATE) 
                          ELSE CAST(tbl1.txnDate  AS DATE) BETWEEN @DateTo AND @DateFrom 
                     END
```

Comment: Can you make your question a bit clearer, perhaps by adding the psuedo-code for your query using `BETWEEN`?

Comment: @shree.pat18 I updated my question with a code.

Comment: `CASE` is an *expression*. It has to compute a scalar *value*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT tbl1.Column1,tbl1.Column2 
FROM table1 tbl1
WHERE 
(@DateTo = '1900-01-01' AND @DateFrom = '1900-01-01')
OR 
(
 NOT (@DateTo = '1900-01-01' AND @DateFrom = '1900-01-01') 
 AND (CAST(tbl1.txnDate  AS DATE) BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo)
 )
```

From what I understand, '1900-01-01' is your default value for start and end dates, so you only need a filter if the user has selected some non-default values for start and end dates. Please let me know if this is what you need.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/BNL93097)

Comment: it works but, if you don't mind can you explain the code. I am bit confused with the where clause..

Comment: '1900-01-01' is the default value for both parameters, so unless user has selected a different value the first condition in `WHERE` will always be true, and all records will be returned. If user selects a different value, the second condition is true and the `BETWEEN` filter is applied.

Comment: I expand the query to check employe id, but the problem is it won't filter with employee id, but it filter with txnDate.. When I comment above query, it will filter with employee id. Why is that happening? 
ex After your query I added tbl1.EmployeeId = 1. There is a Employee with that id..
@shree.pat18

Comment: @Spider This is a separate question from the one you have posted. Please ask a new question. You can provide a link to this question for reference.