# Where Clause doesn't Work - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My previous question was this [Case Statement With Between Clause In Sql Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24879981/case-statement-with-between-clause-in-sql-server)

I got a solution and it works. But the problem is when I add another column to the `WHERE` clause, it won't filter with this new column:

```
SELECT 
    tbl1.Column1, tbl1.Column2 
FROM 
    table1 tbl1
WHERE 
    EmployeeId = CASE WHEN @employeeId = '' THEN tbl1.EmployeeId 
                     ELSE @employeeId END
    AND (@DateTo = '1900-01-01' AND @DateFrom = '1900-01-01') OR 
    (NOT (@DateTo = '1900-01-01' AND @DateFrom = '1900-01-01') 
     AND (CAST(tbl1.txnDate  AS DATE) BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo))
```

This code is what I am trying to use. But it doesn't work. I tried hard-coding a value for `EmployeeId`. But it doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must Use `(` and `)` in where clause where you use `And` and `OR` together in order to define priority of each condition:

```
SELECT tbl1.Column1,tbl1.Column2 
FROM table1 tbl1
WHERE EmployeeId = CASE WHEN @employeeId = '' THEN tbl1.EmployeeId ELSE @employeeId END
    AND (
            (@DateTo = '1900-01-01' AND @DateFrom = '1900-01-01')
         OR (
               NOT (@DateTo = '1900-01-01' AND @DateFrom = '1900-01-01')
               AND (CAST(tbl1.txnDate  AS DATE) BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo)
             )
        )
```